# How should we pack Universal Windows Class Libraries with NuGet?

Tags: .net, uwp, nuget, windows-10-universal

I would like to create a NuGet package for my Universal Windows Class Library (UAP10).

I haven't found any good docs describing it. Only this one, but it doesn't mention UWP:

https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/blob/master/docs/guides/Create-UI-Controls.md

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-uwp-packages

Comment: That's for Windows Runtime Components. I would like to do the same, but for a regular UWP class library.

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: What binaries are required? dll and pri files?

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and clarify a little bit more what exactly you are asking from us? Currently it seems to be a little unclear and might get closed as such.

Comment: @SuperJMN Recently I was also having this problem. I had written down detailed steps on how I approach this problem (UWP Class Library + NuGet + Azure DevOps): https://cuteprogramming.wordpress.com/2020/04/26/pack-uwp-class-library-with-nuget/

Some of the key steps are including of XBF file as well as adding dependencies element and files element in the NuSpec file. Hope it helps!